# Emulate three button mouse without occupying alt key

Tags: navigation

I want to emulate a three button mouse in the same time as I want alt key hotkeys to work. This has worked in earlier versions of blender but not anymore.

Why/how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to switch mouse buttons so that the old RMB gesture is in use for selection. (Then I can alt click an edge and have edge loop select working).